# Plot both map and elevation profile views from .shp and .tif?

Tags: r

Say we have a `route.shp` from `ESRI/ArcGIS` origin representing the path or route of a hike or a stream, and a corresponding topographic raster file in a `dem.tif` with matching spatial coordinate system and projection info.

How can we quickly print both the map view and elevation profile in one static or ideally dynamic image? This is a classic view in navigation/outdoor/fitness apps (eg, Strava, or simplified below static image and more detailed below), of say a trip a user went on.

Ideal products would be both a `ggplot2`-like style w/ 1 column by 2 row `plot.png` (like below), and a `plot.html` with an interactive slider tool that scrolls simultaneously through map location and elevation (and ignore the red/green gradient in the profile).  I'm looking more for convenience of `plotly R` than doing a`Shiny` page, so more "off the shelf" than highly customizable, but I understand it seems a tall order to do concisely in open source environment?

[image]

[image]

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(tiff)
#other libraries?

route <- readOGR(".", "route")
topofile <- "dem.tif"
```

Comment: You could plot the hike map and use color for elevation bins.